# Uncaught TypeError: portfolioItems.forEach is not a function

Tags: javascript, foreach, typeerror

> Uncaught TypeError: portfolioItems.forEach is not a function:

```
 const target = event.target.getAttribute("data-target"); 
 portfolioItems.forEach((item) =>{
     console.log(item.getAttribute("data-category"));
 })
```

[image]

Comment: What type of `portfolioItems` ? array or object?

Comment: this is personal portfolio website, or type of array.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: thanks to all of you guys, I fixed this.